# Using microtime() with Sha1 (to produce unique hash)

Tags: php, sha1

```
$hash = sha1(rand().microtime());
```

I intend to store $hash in database.

If I input a string again and again to `Sha1()` it produces the same hash. But If I input it `microtime()` which returns the current Unix timestamp with microseconds - Would it guarantee a different hash for all future calls (as current time will increment). I here assume future calls as calls made to this function with a difference of atleast 1 minute after the previous call?

What would you say?

**I know I can check uniqueness by simply checking if this hash exists already in the database table but I am just interested in knowing if I can kind of assume its unique when used as above.**

Comment: Why not just use AUTO_INCREMENT columns? What is the point of replacing existing functionality with hashing of timestamps?

Comment: I need something complex-looking than some plain number.

Comment: You said you need unique number, AUTO_INCREMENT is the only solution. Then you say you actually need need something "complex-looking". It's very depressing :))

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan maybe he is looking for an API key to hand out to individuals, in this case a AUTO_INCREMENT would not suffice. I mean is your APP ID from facebook for twitter or google an incrementing ID? There are many reasons to not use an AI so as the OP said: chill...

Comment: @Sammaye it would be nice if we didn't have to guess.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan - may be I should have made it clear that I don't want to use AI - but having thought about it I am thinking to use AI alongwith hash :)

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely **NO** hashing function that computes a string with a predefined, finite length can guarantee uniqueness. Any such finite length string has a finite number of possible outputs, but there are an infinite number of inputs.  It's not exactly complicated to see that **any** hashing function will have to deal with collisions.

That being said, the longer the size of the hashed string, the more unlikely a collision.

You can also use things like GUIDs or [uniqid](https://www.php.net/uniqid), but it's the same issue: there is a possibility of a collision.  Extremely unlikely, but possible.

If you need something guaranteed to be unique, use something like `AUTO_INCREMENT`, or some other type of ID to ensure uniqueness.

If you just want something that *looks* complex (but is not in actuality), then ... well, why?  But I guess if you're dead-set on that, try doing something like stuffing the Unique ID into your hash, for example:

```
$hash = $id . sha1(rand().microtime());
```

or:

```
$sha1 = sha1(rand().microtime());
$hash = substr($sha1,0,20). '-'.$id.'-'. substr($sha1,21);
```

Comment: cheers mate - I am going to use part of your solution. +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you **guarantee** uniqueness? No. SHA1 produces a 160 bit hash. There are more than `2^160` possible values obtainable from `microtime`. Thus there will be multiple values that generate the same hash. The hash values will be to all intents and purposes randomly distributed, so you may have a collision even in a relatively small interval of time.

Can you assume uniqueness in practice? Well, since there's no guarantee, it's all probabilistic. It doesn't help to enforce a minimum interval - the probability of a hash collision is the same between any two observations. But the probability is very low, so you might be OK. Depends on whether the world will end if you get one or if you'll just be minorly inconvenienced... ;)

Comment: There is nothing random about `sha1`. What do you mean by that?

Comment: what do you think of Uniqid() @David ?

Comment: I mean that the distribution of hash values is effectively random - you don't need to enumerate `2^160` values before they start recycling. Agree my wording is sub-optimal - will edit.

Comment: Same issue with Uniqid, as the comments there show. It's not **guaranteed** uniqueness. But like this method, extremely unlikely to produce duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

use [uniqid()](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) you don't need to create your own

Comment: would it guarantee a unique (without needing me checking for unique) ?

Comment: I'll give you a dollar every time you get a duplicate (in your real world usage)- is that good enough?

Comment: It is NOT "guaranteed", but "extremely unlikely"

Comment: lol - yes that'd be good enough - and extremely unlikely is good enough in my scenario as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UUID (as shown from comments on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php ) however that above is not a UUID as such you can't just insert assuming it is unique.

You could say there is a one in a billion chance of conflict. This can be lessened if you take out `rand()` (since this can actually increase the likely hood of `time+rand` equalling something that has occurred) and work on only time, however it all really depends upon accesses, I mean take the `MongoId`, based on time but with enough accesses and shards conflicts can happen and does...

Comment: interesting point if its true about taking-out rand() - as I only added to make it more unique - u know what I mean :P

Comment: @user1421214 Indeed, adding rand() (since it is a random number) can, very unlikely but can, create two duplicates when composed with `microtime()` since you could get a comprised date in the future then have a rand() sometime in the future that gives a low number and boom they equal the same, unlikely the hash would but still...I wouldn't bet my money on that.

Comment: cheers @Sammaye - I am going to test uniqid.

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure.....of its uniqueness and make the column in the db unique to ensure that as well...so that u can rethrow...and $rand() can't be the same always as well as the microtime()